# How to place a banner on one page which reflect on the rest of the pages automatically?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have a banner in a div and I like to place it on home page which automatically reflects on rest of the pages?? Is it possible ?? without placing the code on the each page specifically ??.

Any help would be appreciate :)

Comment: You can write code in a separate PHP file and require that in header where you need to display banner.

Comment: Thanks Mate, I appreciate that!!.. I did the same way.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using PHP, you can write the whole banner in html, then save it as .php (e.g. banner.php). Then somewhere before the content of each of your pages, use PHP's `include` 
keyword

For each of your page you can write it this way:

```
<body>
    <div id='banner'>
        <?php include "/path/to/banner.php"; ?>
    </div>

    <div id='content'>
        <!-- Main content here -->

    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I knew that method , I was looking for javascript but that php works.. its fine!!.

Answer (score 0):

Either this can happen with php as @javiniar-leonard recommends, or you can use css.
In every page the basic structure is the same I guess. So target the div and place the div as background:

```
.main{
     background:url("../your_banner_url.jpg");
}
```

Comment: Thanks bro!!, I'll take a look at @javiniar-leonard recommends.